# Yii2: Custom ErrorActions

Tags: php, yii2

I need different ErrorActions for some controllers. Ist there a way to set die ErrorAction within the controller in Yii2?

For the most controllers the default ErrorAction is defined in the config

```
'components' => [
'errorHandler' => [
    'errorAction' => 'site/error'
],
```

Answer (score 2):

you can modify this in `siteController` and `actionError`.
you can redirect from this action to another action if you want.

Comment: Why make a redirect from one action to another, if you can determine the error in the method actions()

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify erroHandler component in your controller. You can change it in init function of the controller as the following code. Don't forget to define the custom error action in the controller.

```
class YourController extends Controller {

    public function init() {        
        parent::init();
        Yii::app()->errorHandler->errorAction='route/error';
    }

    public function actionError(){
        // error action code goes here
    }

}
```